# You need at least a 1.8 java virtual machine

Tags: java

I am trying to install a tool for streaming market data but I am getting the error

```
You need at least a 1.8 Java Virtual Machine to install dxFeed Market Data Viewer Installer.
Please download it from http://java.com
```

I am running MacOS ventura 13.4.1 with the M1 chip and when I check my java version with java --version I get

```
openjdk 17.0.3 2022-04-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.3.6.1 (build 17.0.3+6-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.3.6.1 (build 17.0.3+6-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Anyone able to tell me what I am missing here as I am confused, it seems I have a much newer version of java than 1.8.

Comment: why don't you state what tool you are talking about. Also show a picture of the error message ('cos eg maybe it's a standard error or maybe it's an error internal to their program). You could also adjust environment variables to experiment re pointing it to the right java.exe

Comment: @barlop - The author did indicate the tool.

Comment: I can tell based on the age of that application there is absolutely no chance of ever running on Apple silicon

Comment: Not all java runtime environments are backward compatible. java deprecates and obsoletes particular methods with each release. Java 1.8 == Java 8, so you may want to try installing a java 8 JRE. you can have multiple versions of jre installed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

### Version numbers changed

In Java 9+, the [version-number scheme changed](https://openjdk.org/jeps/223). If your app is very old, it may not be recognizing the newer version numbers as legitimate. Try installing a JDK product for the latest version of Java 8 to see if that works.

### `JAVA_HOME`

You might need to point your app to your JDK  installation. That might involve setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable. See sister site StackOverflow.com for many posts on this issue. Example [search](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20mac%20java%20default%20JDK&tts=st_asaf_macos).

#### *SDKMAN!*

I would suggest (1) Deleting any JDKs you have installed, (2) Installing [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/), a collection of [shell scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script), and then (3) Use SDKMAN! to install a JDK, and set that JDK as the default. You can later use SDKMAN! to install a new JDK, set that as the default, and delete any old unneeded JDK. The SDKMAN! tool works very well on macOS including Macs with Apple Silicon (M1, M2).

### Several JDK vendors

FYI, JDKs are available from many vendors. These include Amazon, Oracle, SAP, Red Hat, Oracle, Microsoft, IBM, Adoptium, BellSoft, and more. They are all based largely on the same open-source codebase housed at the OpenJDK project. All are tested and trustworthy.

If you don't have a favorite vendor, I'd suggest going with [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/) at the Eclipse Foundation. But really any of the vendors will do.

Comment: AT Ramhound.  IBM acquired Red Hat, i'm not sure if one would say they're the same, there might be legal/financial distinctions, and other distinctions.  Also apparently Microsoft have some kind of JDK development going on. https://www.microsoft.com/openjdk    and windows is listed as an OS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK  and also lists macos. Maybe happened in 2021 https://www.theregister.com/2021/04/06/microsoft_openjdk/

Comment: @Ramhound IBM and Red Hat are uperated separately. They each offer JDK products to their respective customers.

Comment: @Ramhound Microsoft has been distributing JDK products for a couple years now. See [*Microsoft Build of OpenJDK™*](https://www.microsoft.com/openjdk). Available for macOS, Linux, and Windows. [Microsoft joined](https://devclass.com/2021/11/05/microsoft-goes-full-in-on-java-joins-java-community-process/) the Java Community Process (JCP) program. And Microsoft [joined the Eclipse Foundation](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2021/08/03/microsoft-expands-support-with-the-eclipse-foundation/), participating in its *Adoptium* project for building and testing JDK products.